# Is possible get the user logged in a WinServer AD with PHP ldap?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I need get the user logged in a **Windows** network with **PHP**?
like

```
request.servervariables("LOGON_USER")
```

from Asp?

Thanks,
Celso.

Answer (score 0):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.ldap.introduction.html

If you are using zend framework you can use Zend LDAP classes

otherwise use php ldap classes

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-compare.php